# Is it okay to use a deep learning frameworks rather than building the neural network from scratch?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, neural-network, deep-learning, frameworks

I'm new to Deep learning. I followed some course materials on internet and I found they are using deep learning frameworks like KERAS, Tensor-flow in order to build deep neural networks. Also I found in some course materials they are building deep neural networks from that scratch rather than using frameworks. So I wanna know since I am new to deep learning what is the best thing for me. Whether using frameworks to build neural networks or building them from scratch. Is there any thing that could be missing if I directly use frameworks rather that building from the scratch.

I know that they have developed frameworks like KERAS to use. But my problem is if we depend on those frameworks will we miss basic theories of those things since I am new to this field...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, its fine, else what would be the purpose of making those frameworks in the first place?

As you found out building neural networks from scratch is not easy, at least by using Keras or other frameworks, you know that these have some degree of validation that they work correctly.

Comment: No i mean i'm a  student who learning deep learning. so that why i asked is there any issue that using frameworks instead of coding from scratch. is there any important things that i would miss if i use frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem by using Keras with no other assumption is that you won't be able to understand the inner working of the framework. Keras is 100k+ lines of code.

Try to use EpyNN before using Keras, it was made for that. Validated against it, it works correctly and is only ~2k lines of code.

[epynn.net](https://epynn.net)

With this you have an all inclusive solution to master "basic theories of those things" as you mention.